# How can I implement loop in this program?

Tags: python, loops

```
# input burger price 
burgerPrice1 = int(input())
burgerPrice2 = int(input())
burgerPrice3 = int(input())
# input drink price
cokePrice = int(input())
spritePrice = int(input())


price1 = burgerPrice1 + cokePrice
price2 = burgerPrice1 + spritePrice
price3 = burgerPrice2 + cokePrice
price4 = burgerPrice2 + spritePrice
price5 = burgerPrice3 + cokePrice
price6 = burgerPrice3 + spritePrice

current = [price1, price2, price3, price4, price5]

print(min(current) - 50)
```

It's frustrating because I know I can implement loop to make this code shorter

Comment: Wrong place to ask. Use tutorials (google them) or the official documentation/tutorial to get to know the language: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html  - SO does not teach you how to code. We are unable to replicate the plethora of tutorials already out there - specializing in teaching how to code.

Comment: You can have two input arrays: `burgerPrice = []` and then `drinkPrice = []`. Then for every element in `burgerPrice` multiply by all `drinkPrice` elements and append the result to the final list

Comment: `I know I can implement loop` you stated in your question. then why did you ask here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use a loop to get input, and append the burger prices to a list:

```
burgerPrices = []

for n in range(3):
    burgerPrice = int(input())
    burgerPrices.append(burgerPrice)

cokePrice = int(input())
spritePrice = int(input())

current = [burgerPrice+cokePrice for burgerPrice in burgerPrices]+\
          [burgerPrice+spritePrice for burgerPrice in burgerPrices]

print(min(current) - 50)
```

Or even better, a list comprehension:

```
burgerPrices = [int(input()) for _ in range(3)]

cokePrice = int(input())
spritePrice = int(input())

current = [burgerPrice+cokePrice for burgerPrice in burgerPrices]+\
          [burgerPrice+spritePrice for burgerPrice in burgerPrices]

print(min(current) - 50)
```